# How do i display a specific row in 2D array?

Tags: c#

How do i display a specific row in 2D array? I didn't study the complicated methods yet so im allowed to use only nested FOR loop and other basic. This is what i have now but it displays all the numbers.

```
int[,] numbers = new int[5, 10] {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
            {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
            {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
            {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
            {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
        };

            Console.WriteLine("Enter row index between 0 - 4: ");
            int r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            

            for (r = 0; r < 5; r++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers in row " + r);
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers[r, c]);
   
                }
            }
```

Output:

```
Enter row index between 0 - 4: 2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
50
```

Comment: it show everything since you printing every row and column values using nested loop `Console.WriteLine(numbers[r, c]);`  change r to the specific row number you want `Console.WriteLine(numbers[0, c]);` without using nested loop only 1 loop can do it

Comment: You accept a value for `r` but then you ignore that and overwrite it in the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Hi check out the method below that accepts the multidimensional array as a first parameter and the row index as a second parameter and displays all the elements of the row in that index to the console.

```
    static void PrintRowElements(int[,] data ,int index)
        {
            //check if the index is out of bounds
            if (index >= data.GetLength(0)|| index<0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index out of bounds, it needs to be less than the length of the row count and  greater than zero");
                return;
            }   
            //get the number of columns from the length of the second dimension
            var colCount = data.GetLength(1);   
            for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
            {
              Console.Write(data[index, j] + " ");
            }
        }
```

Then in your main method you can define the 2D array and pass the index of the row you would like to print elements for to the method above.

```
static void Main(string[] args){
  //define the index 
  var index =1;
  //define the 2D array
    int[,] numbers = new int[5, 10] {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
            {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
            {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
            {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
            {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
        };
    //print out the elements of that row to the console
    PrintRowElements(numbers, index);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] numbers = new int[5, 10] {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
            {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
            {21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
            {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40},
            {41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50}
        };

            Console.WriteLine("Enter row index between 0 - 4: ");
            int r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            

            for (int i = r ; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers in row " + i);
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i, c]);
   
                }
                break;
            }
```

Output :

```
Enter row index between 0 - 4: 
0
Numbers in row 0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: you don't need nested loop for this